# SharePoint Online - People Column Customisation - Suppress the place holder image on a empty field

Tags: json, sharepoint

I have been trying to get a profile picture to appear in a modern list on SharePoint using the "People" column type, this works fine in classic SharePoint but doesn't in the modern list.  So I've turned to customising the column using JSON and the example from [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/column-samples/person-roundimage-format) (same code below)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "width": "32px",
        "height": "32px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-radius": "50%"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + @currentField.email",
            "title": "@currentField.title"
          },
          "style": {
            "position": "relative",
            "top": "50%",
            "left": "50%",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "auto",
            "margin-left": "-50%",
            "margin-top": "-50%"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This works great with the exception that if the field is empty it gets populated with the default profile picture place holder image as you can see here

[People column showing default place holders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtTFx.jpg)

My question is there any way I can suppress this image so if the field is empty it looks empty on the list view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "width": "32px",
        "height": "32px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-radius": "50%"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "=if(length(@currentField.email)==0, '', '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + @currentField.email)",
            "title": "=if(length(@currentField.email)==0,'',@currentField.Title)"
          },
          "style": {
            "position": "relative",
            "top": "50%",
            "left": "50%",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "auto",
            "margin-left": "-50%",
            "margin-top": "-50%"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```